# How can to initialize the struct with a definition?

Tags: c, struct

I have a following definition in my config file and want to initialize automatically my structure while definiting in compile time. My aim is myStruct.setting[0].line[1].number to be 5. But I get an error while definiting. How can I initialize it like I want?

```
#define MY_DEFINITION \
{\
  {\
    {"menu"    ,20},\
    {"setting" , 5},\
  },\
  {\
    {"menu2"   ,50},\
    {"setting2",15},\
  },\
}

typedef struct{
  struct{
    struct{
      char name[16];
      uint16_t number;
    }line[20];
  }setting[2];
}MyStruct_t;

MyStruct_t myStruct=MY_DEFINITION;
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be *20* elements of the inner structure in the initializer?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your use of a macro (which is what the blocks of code defined with a `#define` are called).  Try it without the macro and see if that works first.

Comment: Remove the comma(s) before the closing `}`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie which commas?

Comment: @EugeneSh.No, it should initalize only two struct, the rest of it be empty

Comment: it gives the "extra brace group at end of initializer" error.

Comment: C is zero(0)-indexed, so your initialization occurs at line[0] instead of line[1] -- once you get the other issues resolved; myStruct.setting[0].line[1].number to be 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an initializer out manually before converting to a macro.  I used:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
  struct {
    struct {
      char name[16];
      uint16_t number;
    } line[20];
  } setting[2];
} MyStruct_t;

MyStruct_t mst =
{                                   // structure as a whole
    {                               // setting
        {                           // setting[0]
            {                       // line
                { "name",   16 },   // line[0]
                { "number",  1 },   // line[1]
            }
        },
        {                           // setting[1]
            {                       // line
                { "zoo",   16 },    // line[0]
                { "bronx",  1 },    // line[1]
                { "new",    0 },    // line[2]
                { "york",   5 },    // line[3]
            }
        }
    }
};

#define MY_DEFINITION \
{\
    {\
        {\
            {\
                { "menu",     20 },\
                { "setting",   5 },\
            }\
        },\
        {\
            {\
                { "menu2",    50 },\
                { "setting2", 15 },\
            }\
        }\
    }\
}

MyStruct_t myStruct = MY_DEFINITION;
```

First I got the initializer without the macro to compile.  Then I rewrote the macro to include the extra braces that the manual edition shows are necessary.  If you're truly determined, you can investigate eliminating braces from the working versions, but it is probably better to work with the fully braced initializer.

May I say — that is a horrid structure to work with!

Comment: Indeed, the braces around array initializers were missing (I found out after puzzling....)

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Thank you. I know wrong about using braces while using any structure.

Comment: Why it's horrid structure? If I initialize it as you show, c file will be very complicated.

Comment: It's horrid (or, at least, unpleasant and tricky to work with) because there are two levels of arrays inside with no auxilliary information alongside them.  It is adding levels of complexity (as evidenced by the extra braces needed) to no apparent purpose.